# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I get this error when trying generate a debug apk for update an app directly on the device (Android - React Native):

> Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session :
> >     INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package prensa.com signatures do
> >     not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Im sure that version code and version name were incremented and the package name is the same.

Also, the keystore and other keys are same used before.

Where is the error?

Comment: It means you already have it installed. Try removing the old instance of the app and reinstalling.

Comment: The app on device has version code 1 and version name 1.0. The new apk has version code 2 and version name 1.1. It should update it ¿right?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it doesn't go on version numbers/names it goes on package name. Installing two apps with the same package name will simply not be allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met the same error today.And I found this`http://blog.bihe0832.com/android-v2-issue.html`.It's in Chinese.The key points describe below:

> After package your apk file, unzip it,check the file
>   META-INF/ANY-NAME.SF.I sign the apk with `jarsigner` command line
>   tool.I found that the `alias` putted after the jar-file when exec the
>   `jarsigner`, will used as the `ANY-NAME`.Then open the ANY-NAME.SF, if
>   you found a line of `X-Android-APK-Signed: 2`,That's the cause of the
>   error.Resign your apk,if the line of code gone, the apk will be
>   installed success.

Answer (score 69):

Just in case if somehow your old application is not removed 100% or its data is not removed.

Try:

```
adb uninstall "com.yourapp.yourapp"
```

Comment: nice !! for me it was `adb uninstall io.ionic.starter` on linux

Comment: stucked for 2hours. Thanks :) +1

Comment: but what if you want to keep the old data because you're migrating to a new version?

Answer (score 8):

for me this was because i tried installing a debug version on a phone that already had a production version installed. in other words, the installed app was signed with the `release.keystore` file, while the debug version is signed with `debug.keystore` file.

so i just uninstalled the app so that it could install the app that was signed with `debug.keystore` file.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you know which device adb is dealing with.

I had multiple devices available. I couldn't understand why uninstalling on my emulator didn't get rid of the message. It turned out that my hardware phone was plugged into the computer to charge, and also had USB debugging enabled which was confusing adb.

Disabling USB debugging on my hardware phone, and uninstalling the app on the emulator got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

**INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE**

Please uninstall your Previous APk and install again updated APK

```
gradlew clean

npm start -- --reset-cache

react-native run-android
```

Comment: `gradlew clean` is a bit confusing. From project directory run `cd android && ./gradlew clean`.

Answer (score 2):

If you already install app on your device, please **`uninstall it`** by delete your app and rerun **`npx react-native run-android`** again.

hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the problem after upgrading react-native version from **0.59.0** to **0.59.8** . Manually deleting the app from device and then running `react-native run-android` solved the problem for me