# .apk Built from GitHub Workflow not Compatible with Local Build

Tags: android, github, apk, github-actions, android-keystore

When I try to install an .apk built from a GitHub workflow over one that I built locally, I get the following error:

```
$ adb install -r /path/to/package-debug.apk
Performing Push Install
/path/to/package-debug.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 14.1 MB/s (4047241 bytes in 0.275s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/package-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

I can install the GitHub built version if I uninstall the locally built package first.

I have run `aapk` on both packages to make sure they were built with the same `min` & `target` values. My guess is that the key signatures are different, but I'm not sure. The build is configured to use the default signing config (`signingConfig signingConfigs.debug`) in `build.gradle`. Do different versions of the Android development tools provide different versions of the debug signing keystore? Or does each installation generate a unique keystore file? Is there a way I can get more information on why the installation fails?

I also noticed that the file sizes are different:

```
$ wc -c local-debug.apk
4085058 local-debug.apk

$ wc -c remote-debug.apk
4047241 remote-debug.apk
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757862/install-failed-update-incompatible-package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previous), but the answers are about uninstalling first. I need to figure out how to make the remote build compatible with the local one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution before posting this question. And as I haven't seen the answer on StackOverflow, I will post it in case it might help someone else.

It appears that the Android development tools generate unique debug keystores on systems that don't already have one. I was assuming that the keystore file was a universal one. So to solve the problem, I simply included the keystore file with the source code (I'm assuming is safe as it is meant for debugging only) & set its location in the `gradle.build` file.

In this particular case, I put the keystore file in the same directory as the `gradlew` script & added the following line to `app/build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs.debug.storeFile file("../debug.keystore")
```

**Edit:** Though now I have deleted it as the head developer felt it was unsecure. So, use this solution at your own risk & don't use debug keys for signing official releases of your software.